# Multiple vectors with different types

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to create a small proof-of-concept database system that uses Tables to store data.  A "Table" is a collection of columns.  Each column can have a different type.  Each table can have any number of columns.

Ideally, I'd like something like:

```
class Table {
  map<string, vector<T>> cols; //string is name of col, vector holds data
}
```

However, the type of the vector has to be known at compile time, so I can't have multiple types (vector int, vector double, etc) in the same map.

Do I need:

```
class Table {
  map<string, vector<int>>    int_cols;
  map<string, vector<double>> double_cols;
  //etc...
}
```

For each type that I'd like to be able to store?
I feel like there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: How about a `Column` base class, with derived `IntColumn`, `MarineMammalColumn`, etc., and `Table` contains a `vector<Column*>`?

Comment: Can you take a look at [Type Erasure](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i) ?

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](http://ideone.com/CZyAl8)

Answer (score 0):

Actually C++ is not the best choice to manage dynamic types. Consider this member of vector:

```
reference operator[](size_type index);
```

If the type is not statically resolved, how will the return value be interpreted under binary level? For a language lack of meta class info support, there is no elegant universal solution for such a problem. However, if the types of the values you intend to store are enumerable, I may suggest you to try boost::any or boost::variant:

```
map<std::string, boost::any> cols;
```

It really looks bad when you have to fetch a value:

```
if (cols[key].type() == typeid(std::vector<int>)) {
    process(cols[key].any_cast<std::vector<int>>());
} else if (cols[key].type() == typeid(std::vector<double>)) {
    process(cols[key].any_cast<std::vector<double>>());
}
...
} else {
    throw std::runtime_error("Oops! Seems that I missed a type :-(");
}
```